# Cascading list boxes, with multi-select

Tags: sharepoint

I wound up modifying the source from a publically posted POC: http://datacogs.com/datablogs/archive/2007/08/26/641.aspx, which is a custom field definition for cascading drop downs.  The modifications were to allow parent-child list boxes where a user can multiselect for filtering and selecting the values to be written back to a SharePoint list.   I got the parent-child cascading behavior working, but the save operation only takes the first value that is selected from the list box.  I changed the base type for the custom field control from "SPFieldText" to "SPMultiLineText", along with changing the FLD_TYPES field definition values from:
Text to Note and this did not work.  So, I changed the field control base type to "SPFieldMultiChoice" and the FLD_TYPES to "MultiChoice" and still get the same result, which is only the first value that's selected, writing to the SharePoint list.

Does anyone have any idea how to get a custom field with multiple selections to write those multiple selections to a SharePoint list?

Thanks for taking the time to read through my post.

Cheers,
~Peter

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this by inheriting from `SPFieldLookup` and overriding its internal handling of `AllowMultipleValues`:

1. In your FLDTYPES_*.xml set `<ParentType>LookupMulti</ParentType>`
2. In your extension of `SPFieldLookup`, be sure to override `AllowMultipleValues` (always `true`), `FieldValueType` (probably `typeof(SPFieldLookupValueCollection)`) and `FieldRenderingControl`. I also set `base.LookupField = "LinkTitleNoMenu"`, though in retrospect I'm not sure why. :)
3. In your field editor control's `OnSaveChange()`, set the field's `Mult` value to `true`.

To set `Mult`, you can either string manipulation on `field.SchemaXml`:

```
string s = field.SchemaXml;
if (s.IndexOf(" Mult=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0)
    field.SchemaXml = s.Insert(s.IndexOf("/>", StringComparison.Ordinal), " Mult=\"TRUE\" ");
```

Or use reflection:

```
    var type = field.GetType();
    var mi = type.GetMethod("SetFieldBoolValue", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    mi.Invoke(field, new object[] { "Mult", true });
```

It's been a while, so I might be forgetting something, but that should be most of it.

Comment: Another option is to use XmlDocument to modify SchemaXml:
http://www.tonstegeman.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=88